# How to integrate a condition in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, conditional-operator

Using the below script I was able to create a boxplot for 2 classes, eg LB/B and LP/P.
Now I only want to plot these 2 classes if a condition is met. There is another column called 'source' by which the class was established, eg VKGL or ClinVar. I only want to use LB/B and LP/P classes from VKGL. How could I integrate such a condition in the below script?

```
data %>%
  filter(classification %in% c("LB/B", "LP/P")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(classification, `total energy`)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
```

I searched in ggplot documentation and on the internet but could not find a solution.

Comment: Perhpas you want `filter(classification %in% c("LB/B", "LP/P"), source %in% "VKGL")`?

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example - can you share a sample of what your data looks like using `dput()`? It makes it much easier for others to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add more conditions to your filter by stringing them together with the "and" operator `&`:

```
data %>% filter(classification %in% c("LB/B", "LP/P") & source == "VGKL") %>%  
 ggplot(aes(classification, total energy)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `classification %in% c("LB/B", "LP/P")
  & source == "VKGL"`.
Caused by error in `source == "VKGL"`:
! comparison (==) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: What would a entry in your source column look like? What is the data type?